# cant manually enter subclass names in xcode new file, only a drop down list

Tags: xcode, class, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, subclassing

is it just my version of xcode or am I missing something. I am following a tutorial and it is telling me to right click Classes and select new file which i can do. it then says select iOS\CocoaTouch\Objective c class which i can do. However the tutorial then says For the subclass field enter CCLayer and click next, but the window im seeing has a subclass dropdown list that only contains NSObject, UITableViewCell and UIView. Have I got a version where I cant type in the subclass manually or am I missing something?

Comment: I've answered this under your other question. You can just click on the NSObject field and write anything you want. What build of xcode do you have?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge in XCode 4 you have that option.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file you can do this....

@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController

In the above statement instead of UIViewController you can use your own class